# How to generate custom pagination and sorting instead of using default ui-bootstrap?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting conflicts when I am using ui-bootstrap. please help to solve this problems?

Comment: what is the conflicts ? what are the errors you face ? post your code as well..

Comment: i am getting conflicts like responsive and bootstrap data time picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try 
[dirPagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) which will include sorting and pagination functionality within it.

Comment: for this we need to add any js file